# Why doesn't my GameMaker step event work?

Tags: game-maker

So I want to make some kind of floor that which the player when walks in gets his movement reduced but im having thousand of different issues implementing this since it doesnt appear to do anything ...

So i have tried different way:

1 - I have tried Step Event which had the following script:

```
if keyboard_check(ord('A'))
{
    player.x = -5;
}
if keyboard_check(ord('D'))
{
    player.x = -5;
}
if keyboard_check(ord('W'))
{
    player.x = -5;
}
if keyboard_check(ord('S'))
{
    player.x = -5;
}
```

2 - I have tried a Collision Event with the same code

3- I have tried a Step event with collision detection on a script

None of these options seem to work at all ... Can you help me?

Comment: There are two possibilities here: 1 - GameMaker is at fault (which is probably not the case) 2 - You don't have an instance of the object in the room. It's really hard to diagnose the problem without seeing screens(since Game-Maker is a visual tool for Game Development).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code , I can tell that you are setting the player's coordinates to -5. You should have a method that calculates the delta(or time/frames passed) and in your render method , draw the player at the x,y after you have setted the players coordinates multiplying them with the players velocity(that you should set in your code). So , here is some pseudo code:

```
//Calculating the delta
 //while initialization for first time:
 frame = currentTime // CALL THIS AT THE START OF YOUR LEVEL
 //while calculating
 delta = currentTime - frame
 frame = current time

//The player instance should have 2 variables , velocityX and velocityY
//Calculating the Δx ,Δy

x = x + (delta * velocityX)//move right
//or
x = x - (delta * velocityX)//move left

//same thing for the Y
```

Hope that this helps!You may have to make huge corrections tough